# How to allow GStreamer's `tcpserversrc` to receive an RTMP stream and demux it?

Tags: gstreamer

I currently have a non working GStreamer pipeline as follows:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
    tcpserversrc host="172.29.38.56" port=1935 \
    ! flvdemux name=demux
    # (remainder truncated)
```

The gist of what I'm trying to achieve is to allow GStreamer to receive an RTMP stream then demux, transcode and forward the streams.

How do I take the raw data from the `tcpserversrc` and tell GStreamer that it is an FLV/RTMP stream?

I have this working in FFMPEG with the following:

```
ffmpeg \
    -re \
    -v info \
    -stream_loop -1 \
    -listen 1 \
    -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app
    # (remainder truncated)
```

But I'd ideally like to experiment with using GStreamer for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. RTMP is a complex communication protocol. You use `rtmpsrc` or `rtmp2src` for that. E.g:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
    rtmpsrc location="rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app" \
    ! flvdemux name=demux
    # (remainder truncated)
```

Comment: rtmpsrc and rtmp2src are concerned with getting a stream from an established endpoint. I want to receive a stream (see the FFMPEG example).

Comment: Then it is not clear to me what you are asking for.